# How to use MinMaxScaler when X_train and X_test are different sizes

Tags: keras, lstm, normalization

I'm using an LSTM through Keras to predict a time series. My inputs are the previous measurements of one time series(v1) at time 0-59 seconds and the goal is to predict the measurement of a different variable(v2) at time 60 (based on those previous 60 seconds of v1 measurements). The training actually performs really well, but I'm hitting an error when it comes to normalizing the test data.

I've seen all posts about using .fit_transform() on x_train and only using .transform() on x_test, and this works when I train on half the data and test on the other half, but I'm running into an error with MinMaxScaler because when I train on 70% of the data (resulting in a matrix of size 1920x60 for x_train) and testing on the remaining 30% (resulting in a matrix of size 960x60):

I've got a scaler set up for the v1 (X_train) and a different one set up for the v2 (Y_train), but when I go to scale X_test using the .transform() only of the v1 scaler, I get the following error:

ValueError: X has 960 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 1920 features as input.
I understand the logic behind this (MinMaxScaler saves the min/max it was fit on in the .fit_transform step), but how are people getting around this issue? Am I missing something completely?

TIA

Comment: think carefully. Firstly, *'ValueError: X has 960 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 1920 features as input'* do you really have 1920 and 960 *features*? Secondly, what exactly does MinMaxScaler do? Try take 1 time series as train and 2 as test and apply MinMaxScaler on paper and pen. Does the size and/or number of features matter?

Comment: I left out an important note: I am transposing the matrix before MinMaxScaler bc I want to normalize by row (the features for one observation are just the previous 60 seconds) and MinMaxScaler doesn't have a flag for that (default is column) - so I know I have 60 features only per observation (which I have 1920 of for training and 960 for test). I would assume I wouldn't have this problem if I didn't transpose, but I don't want to transpose by column

Comment: I see. In this case, I don't think the vanilla `MinMaxScaler` works, as it assumes feature-wise scaling. However, since the scaling of each observation is independent of others, why not just write a function which scales an observation, and loop this function over all observations?

Comment: I think that would work for the training data, but I'm not sure how I would apply that to the testing data if it's a different size since there's supposed to be this separation in normalization to prevent data leakage to the model. In the real world application, we would be receiving data in real-time

Comment: There is no concern of data leakage. Data leakage happens when information of test data is leaked to train, but IIUC for your case the transformation is independent among samples, i.e. knowing anything about the test set does not affect how train set is treated and vice versa.